# Site Map - Accesibility question regarding use of overlay?

Tags: xhtml, accessibility

Quick question - Does it matter (accessibility wise) if a site map is placed in a hidden div in each page and displayed in overlay on request!?

Just because this would be a best quick fit solution regarding a site I need to alter!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach would be to have your sitemap on a separate page with it's own URL. This would then allow you to:

1. Provide a link to the sitemap e.g. on your 404 page to help users find what they are looking for
2. Add a `<link>` tag to the `<head>` of each page specifying the sitemap as the index of the site e.g. go to http://www.apple.com/uk/ and view source

If your sitemap is *only* included in a hidden tag shown via a lightbox overlay then in terms of accessibility you'd have to think of how users with JavaScript and / or CSS disabled would access it, how this would affect users using screen readers, etc.

Plus having your sitemap available on its own URL would help search engine spiders when crawling your site.

You could always add the sitemap lightbox overlay effect as a [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) though for users whose browsers *can* view it this way, but as you mentioned you were after a quick solution this might not be that feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Its not required to place in the hidden div for the sitemap link.

Comment: Hi, Sorry - the link would be present on each page, but when clicked the map will appear on page in a lightbox overlay.